# Google Drive API (v3) root files.list throws Unknown Error

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am using **googleapis** in a Ionic 5 project. Did the Google Plus Authentication, with Ionic Google Plus native plugin, and got the access token.

```js
this.gPlus.login({
        "scopes": "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "webClientId": environment.GDRIVE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        "offline": true 
      }).then((gUser) => {
      return gUser.accessToken;
})
```

Now, I and using the access token token returned to get the list of files from my Google Drive, using **platform.js** . Response is an Unknown Error

```js
async get_root_folder_list(gtoken) {
    let apiKey = environment.GAPI_KEY;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + gtoken);
    headers = headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    headers = headers.append("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    let _url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=${apiKey}&q=trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20'root'%20in%20parents`;
    return await this.http.get(_url, {headers: headers}).toPromise();    
  }
```

*ERROR: Http failure response for [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20'root'%20in%20parents](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse%20and%20%27root%27%20in%20parents): 0 Unknown Error*

What am I doing wrong here? I could not find any information that could solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: This seems specific to your Ionic/platform.js setup. I tried REST calls on a different language with the same headers and URL parameters and it worked, so it's probably not an API issue. I'd also like to note that you do not need to use an API key if you have an `access_token`, see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_4). I suggest searching for `HTTP failure 0 Unknown Error` since that does seem to return similar issues like [this one](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2021/09/ionic-4-http-failure-response-for.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Daniel. Yes. It seems specific to using token provided by Google Plus plugin with the Google REST API. They (REST API) do work in my web application. Just not in the mobile app. Also, platform.js is being discontinued as per this notification https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html. Currently working on doing this with Node.js backend.